# android group notification show last notification instead of first one

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to implement group notification like whatsapp. But issue here is first 6 notification are visible to user. How can i display the last 6 notification instead of first one.

PFB demo code for same:

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import static android.R.attr.value;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Notification.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new Notification.InboxStyle();
    private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 237;
    private static int NOTIFICATION_ID1 = 237;

    final static String GROUP_KEY_EMAILS = "group_key_emails";

    static int i=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");
        send(++i+"");

    }


    public void send(String message)
    {
        NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle(message+"Lanes");
        builder.setContentText(message+"Notification from Lanes"+value);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(message+"Enter Content Text");
        inboxStyle.addLine(message+"hi events "+value);
        builder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
        nManager.notify("App Name",NOTIFICATION_ID ,builder.build());

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Use a string array to store new notification messages.
Each time a new notification is generated,cancel the notification and 
add messages to the notification builder from the end of the list.
I tried this and it worked !

```
private final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 237;
ArrayList<String> notificationText = new ArrayList<>();
Notification.InboxStyle inboxStyle ;

static int i=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");
    send(++i+"");

}


public void send(String message)
{
    notificationText.add(message);
    NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nManager.cancelAll();

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    inboxStyle = new Notification.InboxStyle();
    builder.setContentTitle(message+"Lanes");
    builder.setContentText(message+"Notification from Lanes"+value);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle(message+"Enter Content Text");
    for(int i=notificationText.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
        inboxStyle.addLine(notificationText.get(i)+"hi events "+value);
    }
    builder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
    nManager.notify("App Name",NOTIFICATION_ID ,builder.build());

}
```

Comment: i can see notfication is coming but as soon i open notification tray its not visible there

Comment: How to handle custom remote view in this ?

Comment: basicaly i need add a line at the end of notification show user the message like you have recieve 10 message

Comment: You mean the text when notification is collapsed? setContentText is used for that.

Comment: no Anindita  I mean if i used the remote view in the code provide by you i can see last 7 notifications but in that remote view notfication its not showing the entire layout due to space insufficient